# Storing admin username and password

Tags: node.js, security, environment-variables, ejs, admin

I'm creating a website for my college. I want to include an admin panel, so college authorities can post some news on the home page and upload images to the college galary.
Now my question is, where to store admin username and password securely. It is not possible to store in database because there will not be a registration process. I intend to store them on environment variables, but i don't know if it is secure or not, and chrome also giving security warning because password is not encrypted. Please give me suggestions. By the way, I'm using Nodejs with ejs and mongodb.

Comment: In the user table have a userType field which represents whether it is a admin or a user and just like other users, the admin credentials will be in db as well

Comment: Agreed. The security of admin password does not come from moving the credentials somewhere else, but from using strong passwords and strong Key Derivation Functions for password hashing (scrypt, bcrypt).